# What is the best way to procedurally texture an object without the hard edged seams I am getting?

Tags: texturing, materials

I have a simple image I made which can be tiled to produce a relatively nice texture. I followed some tutorials with chainmail and using the blend function it looks nice, but for other textures I cannot blend them. My nodes are set up for Texture Coordinates -> Vector Transform -> Mapping -> Image Texture (set to Box, which is what gives the best result but has hard edges) -> Principled -> Material output.
Is there a way to made it seamlessly wrap around a complex mesh like a body. I don't mind some mild stretching as a compromise.
[image: hard edges on procedural texturing]

Comment: Hello, try increasing the "Blend" factor in the image texture node. This should decrease the edge visibility

Comment: This results in an undesirable effect. For some I can blend, this one I cannot because it looks bad.

Comment: if you want only quads it's like solving a topolgy problem, maybe use an addon like Instant Remesh to make only quads from your mesh then find a way to bake the topology?

Comment: The mesh is mostly quads now,https://imgur.com/oA3Simf

Comment: in that case you can duplicate, subdivide, use a Wireframe modifier and bake the result?

Comment: Whats the process for that?

Comment: What I mean is how will baking the topology help? I am a bit new to blender.

Comment: I meant you can generate this kind of pattern using a Wireframe modifier on your mesh, then baking the result, I didn't mean you could use the pattern you're showing right now

Comment: Ah, I see. While true, what if I have a complex repeating texture? I'm not concerned about this specific texture so much as the way to make it wrap without issues.

Answer (score 1):

For your textures, if the *Image Texture Blend* option doesn't fix the problem, I don't think there's any easy way to hide the visible seams. You could try to fix it in *Texture Painting* mode with the *Stencil* or the *Clone* brush, but it will really depend on the texture I guess.

So I probably misunderstood your question, but for the specific texture you're showing, a kind of grid, you could use your current topology:

- Duplicate your object, hide the original. As suggested by Lemon, if you want a more dense and uniform net, use the *Remesh* tool/ *Voxel* option in the *Properties panel > Object Data > Remesh*:

[image]

- If you want the topology to be rotated 45°, select all and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Unsubdivide* with an *Iteration* of 1 (*Operator* box), like that:

[image]

- Go in *Edit* mode, switch to *Face* Select, select all, press <kbd>i</kbd> twice to inset the faces. Keep these faces selected, give them a material (here orange). <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> to invert the selection, give the strokes another material (here red):

[image]

- Unhide the original torso, it must overlap its copy, go in *Edit* mode, select all, unwrap (*Smart UV Project* mode), in the *UV Editor* create a new image (size 2048 x 2048 for example), in the *Shader Editor* create an *Image Texture* node, don't plug it for the moment, load the image you've created. Make sure you're in Cycles, select the copy, shift select the original, go in the *Properties panel > Render > Bake*, choose *Bake Type > Diffuse*, disable *Influence > Direct* and *Indirect*, enable *Selected to Active*, give a bit of *Extrusion* value, click on *Bake*:

[image]

- Once the map as been created, plug the *Image Texture* node into the *Principled BSDF* (or *Diffuse*), the map is now displayed on the surface of the original torso. If you use a *Subdivision Surface* modifier You may need to give some corrections in *Texture Painting mode*:

[image]
[image]

Comment: If want to follow the mesh geometry (but this is not exactly the question, though), use remesh.

Comment: could you please tell a bit more? Yes that was not the question but I thought using the topology was a way to answer, I don't see how to make a grid all over the body without any visible seam, using the topology seemed like a solution

Comment: few in fact... the question is about mapping not only a grid but any shape (and this is nearly a research project/algorithm)... but if you want to have (from your answer) a quad geometry which is regular, remesh will create quads with uniform size... so closer to the question. I've not tried it, though. Bon, je n'ai pour autant pas de vraie solution pour cette question, @moonboots.

Comment: oh yes I'm going to edit; merci  ;)

Comment: though, consider my comment was a general idea, not a poc... I don't want to lead things in a bad way...

Comment: okay I read again the comments and this grid was just an example, I still leave my comment

Comment: What I am hearing is that for 'complex' meshes, it has to be UV unwrapped to get a good result.

Comment: It really depends on the kind of texture you're talking about, if the texture has big visible patterns, it will be hard to make it work on complex objects like a costume for example, because we will probably see the seam, the trick for this kind of case is to put the seam where the camera won't see it, it may also be fixed with some painting correction